Font selection UI
Most application where you can choose a font will simply list all available font, alphabetically. Optionally, they may offer a preview by writing font font name in the font itself (like word does).
Given that there are usually hundreds of installed fonts on a system, finding a font in these list is just insufferable. Most people I know just memorized 2-3 fonts they know and like.
Examples: Bellow are the font selection from Word, Gimp, and Paint.net. Three widely used tools that suffer from the same problem : search through the catalog is a pain, because :

the alphabetical sort
the number of fonts
these are "temporary" (or "popup"?) windows: any click outside the window will close it. Obviously, it's not meant for the user to spend a long time with this menu open, testing multiple font.

Why don't these tool use a better system?
How could a font selection tool (based on app or system available font, not online!) offer a better way to choose a font?
Obviously, on of the first step would be categorizing the fonts. Why aren't they already categorized?




What exactly is the question here? Are you questioning the font selection system in general? Or, are you looking for suggestions to find a particular font?

Are you questioning the font selection system in general? : yes (at least for the 3 example provided). The question is How could a font selection tool offer a better way to choose a font?, @EmmanuelCuevas showed a wonderful example of a good font selection UI. There was an additional question Why don't these tool use a better system? for which I don't have yet an answer (my guess being, they don't care).

It is simply not required. Most OS come with their basic licensed or open-sourced font-families, which users are familiar with. A new user may be not. But then again a normal user does not even understand the difference between sans- and serif fonts. You are questioning from a graphic designer point of view. A complex system as the Adobe example filled with all types of typographic jargon is pointless to most users. Imagine a system like that inside Microsoft Word – complicated, time consuming with high learning curve.

I'm not a designer, nor a graphist. And I'm definitely not familiar with any font family. Looking at the answer bellow I don't really get the difference between serif and slab serif, or sans serif and mono. But the "tag" section seems pretty obvious (and maybe enough for a layman?). What is sure is that when I was looking the a font that looked like handwritting, I spent 30 seconds on the MS word selection tool, then went straight to google, because its so unpractical. (and word is the best of the 3. Gimp one is really useless)

This is not my domain, but I have the feeling that any list of 250+ items (rough estimation on my ms word installation) should do better that alphabetically sorted and have at least some search helper. So I wonder why it's not the case for fonts... User being familiar seems weak to me : I've used word all my life, yet struggle every-time (which is rarely) I want something else than the default font. The learning curve of "just a list of font" is awful: you have to test each fonts one by one to see what you like. A "similar to current font, but different" (like the "tag") could work wonder.

That's a good observation.
When I was designing an outcome for a project I always hate the moment when I had to select a font. I think that with the time Adobe did a good job how to reduce frustration from designers when selecting fonts.
If you go to the fonts.adobe site, you can have a filter to identify the best font for your design and fav it. Once you select it, the font will appear on top of the list in the tool you are using. They have implemented the same in each dropdown reducing time in defining the best font for you.
Font Filter


Since users often have a general idea of the style they’re looking for, allow them to filter fonts based on these major categories:

Sans-Serif
Serif
Slab Serif
Handwriting
Display

These styles help users narrow their options quickly without scrolling through an overwhelming list.
Font Preview with Actual Style:
Display each font name in its respective typeface, allowing users to recognize the style instantly. It makes it much easier for users to identify fonts based on visual appearance rather than just names.
Customizable Text Preview:
Offer a text input field where users can type in custom text to see how it will look in different fonts. It is beneficial since some fonts have limited glyph support, and users may want to ensure that all necessary characters are in the chosen font.
Favorites or Recently Used Fonts:
Include a feature for users to bookmark favorite fonts or quickly access recently used fonts. It can save time for users who frequently return to specific fonts.
